# React native cannot install application

Tags: android, react-native

`react-native run-android` is producing the following error output:

[image: Error output]

The android studio logcat shows the following:

[image]

Everything was working fine a week back. But suddenly, the metro bundler stopped working.

Comment: The bundler server should be running in a different window, and will have an error message on the display.  Check that.

Comment: The bundler server shows nothing. It just says:
`Starting the app on MVINWONR4SZD7HCQ (adb -s MVINWONR4SZD7HCQ shell am start -n com.reno/com.reno.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.reno/.MainActivity }`

Comment: That's not the bundler server.  That's the output from adb -- the bundler server should be running in another window (`react-native run-android` will launch one if it isn't running).

Comment: There is no other terminal window appearing. `react-native log-android` shows nothing.

Comment: Have you tried clean build with `cd android && gradlew clean`? Although I don't think that would make a difference, just curious. @Jules is right in his recommendation. Also try closing Android Studio and then run on emulator/device, that should start the separate server @Jules is talking about.

Comment: Did a clean build. Closed android studio and then again executed the command, I find nothing. Even the debugger on chrome shows me the same error output.

Comment: Now, this is interesting. The debugger shows me the following error:
https://imgur.com/a/jrSWj

Comment: Do you perhaps have another server running on port 8081?

Comment: lsof -i :8081 returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran `react-native start` in another terminal before running `react-native run-android` and the application ran successfully. I think there is an issue with the metro-bundler that it does not start or it stops at some point during bundling.